# Load balancer and serverless NEG isn't working

Tags: google-app-engine

I configured Google Cloud load balancer and serverless NEG to make my app engine work in static IP, but it's not working anyway.
Here are the commands I used for configuration.

```
gcloud beta compute network-endpoint-groups create get-payqin-serverless-neg \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --network-endpoint-type=SERVERLESS  \
    --app-engine-app

gcloud compute backend-services create get-payqin-backend-service \
--global

gcloud beta compute backend-services add-backend get-payqin-backend-service \
--global \
--network-endpoint-group=get-payqin-serverless-neg \
--network-endpoint-group-region=europe-west1

gcloud compute url-maps create get-payqin-url-map \
--default-service get-payqin-backend-service
```

All those commands are just copied from google cloud documentation, only minor changes with parameters.

The project has only one default service in Google App Engine, and it was deployed in europe-west region. I found that europe-west region is same as europe-west1 region in GAE.

I checked the app deployed in GAE was surely working from browser. The load balancer surely has its static ip assigned in frontend.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration.

Please help me with this one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. I finished the configuration. The purpose is to make load balancing IP accessible from the internet, and the IP is routed to GAE.

I had to change static IP from the global type to regional. And the region should be in the same region as GAE instance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document “[Serverless network endpoint groups overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts)”, in the “[Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts#limitations)” section on of the points indicates the following:

-A serverless NEG cannot have any network endpoints such as IP address or port.

You have to take into account that a serverless NEG can represent an App Engine app (Standard or Flex), a specific service within an app or even a specific version of an app, not an IP address.